# DatePicker [ eyecon ] set a range of date jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery-plugins, datepicker, monthcalendar

I am using multi month [Datepicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/)

i am unable set a date range explicitly.

for eg i have to show sep 1st 2012 to 30 aug 2012 as selected on some button click.

documentation has this method but it only  select the start date

`$('selector').DatePickerSetDate(date, shiftTo);`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found answer after going through plug-in code

$("selector").DatePickerSetDate([new Date(2012,8,1), new Date(2012,9,30)],1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('input').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        yearRange: '1920:'
    });
```

hope it can help